# mouse hover disturbing navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created navigation menu, when I move mouse hover on the navigation item, Navigation getting up's and down's, In the below image you can find without mouse over[image: without mouse over]

When I move mouse over on navigation it became like this: can any one help me?
[image]

css :

```
#navigation {
    /* background: #414445 url(../images/navigation/bg.png) repeat-x 0 0; */
        clear: both;
        min-height: 2.2em;
        padding: 0 5px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        float: right;
        top: -45px;
        width: 850px;
}

#navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px;
    float: right;
}

.ie7 #navigation ul {
    padding: 2px;
}

#navigation li, #navigation a {
    display: inline-block;
}

.ie6 #navigation li, .ie7 #navigation li, .ie6 #navigation a, .ie7 #navigation a {
    display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    z-index: 200;
}

#navigation li {
    color:#000;
        position: relative;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-left: 20px;

}
#header_navigation {
        top: 22px;

}
#navigation a {
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ie7 #navigation a {
    padding: 4px 15px;
}

#navigation .aui-dd-drop a {
    cursor: move;
}
/* 
#navigation .selected a, #navigation a:hover, #navigation a:focus, #navigation .child-menu li a, #navigation .aui-dd-dragging, .lfr-navigation-proxy {
    background: #313334;
    border-bottom: #fff solid 2px;
    outline: 0;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px #000;
}
#navigation li:hover{
    border-bottom: #000 solid 2px;

} */


#navigation li:hover .child-menu {
    background: #188091;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 200;
}

.ie6 #navigation li.hover .child-menu {
    background: #1E2529;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 200;
}

.ie6 #navigation li.hover .child-menu, .ie7 #navigation li:hover ul.child-menu {
    left: 0;
    top: 25px;
}

#navigation .child-menu {
    display: none;
}

#navigation .child-menu li {
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    height: 25px;
}

#navigation .child-menu li a {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}

.ie7 #navigation .child-menu li a {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: You can set an absolute position for the sub menus to get rid of the layout problem. Share some codes?

Comment: Images do nothing to help you. You need to show code.

Comment: http://pastie.org/9989356 and http://snag.gy/s5exA.jpg

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle or the entire html/css in this post so we can see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: sorry I can't post html code, because it is written in velocity, all the id and classes will come dynamically. so I can post css only